# Google Calendar Api not successfully call in Marshmallow Version

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-googleapiclient

I am developing App in which i calls the Google Calendar API and it works successfully i get all the events.But,in Marshmallow version i can't get any event,i also give permission to enable the contacts in setting->apps->my_app->Permission->enable contact.

```
   Still Error occurs in calendar Api
   Error : com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also would be needing the calender permission in Marshmallow to access the Google Calender API

Comment: u r saying in google calendar or mobile permission? can you suggest me which permissions are there?